# android studio only starts the virtual machine

Tags: android, android-studio, visual-studio-code

When I recently studied React Native, I needed to use an emulator to test (when I don’t need a mobile phone to run).But every time you have to start Android Studio and then start the emulator, it is very troublesome to operate twice,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start your emulator by using command line, by open your CMD in your sdk folder / emulator. Then try this command

```
emulator -list-avds
```

To list your virtual devices and then

```
emulator -avd <device_name>
```

You can find the detail here
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline#starting

Hope that help. ^^

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. I can also write the command to the bat file on the desktop, and double-click the bat file next time

Answer (score 0):

You can start emulators from the terminal/ CMD without opening Android Studio.

To get the list of AVDs (run from sdk/emultor folder)

`emulator -list-avds`

To run any avd

`emulator -avd avd_name [ {-option [value]} … ]`

or,

`/Users/janedoe/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_23 -netdelay none -netspeed full`

For more details refer - [Official guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline)